# Same Salt Or Different Salts

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

Here's my question: In your experience, is it safer to have a single salt for every hash stored in the PHP file doing the hashing, or is it better to have a different salt for every hashed object and store it in the database with that object?

Comment: amazingly this question has sparked a pretty decent discussion and there are no upvotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The salt only makes sense if it is different for each hashed string.

So, yes, create additional column and put **random** salt there

Comment: The only thing a salt does if it's stored in a database is prevent the hash being looked up in a database. A salt inside the PHP file is more secure unless the software is open source of course.

Comment: @AustinAllover: unless you know algorithm (you need sources for that) - knowledge of the salt and the hash gives nothing. PS: thanks for downvote

Comment: You need to know the algorithm for both cases, it doesn't matter if the hash is in database or in the file. What advantage does the salt inside the database give? and I downvote because I feel your answer is wrong :P

Comment: @AustinAllover: "You need to know the algorithm for both cases" --- exactly. You don't know the algorithm - you cannot bruteforce the password. Regardless of if there is or there is no a static salt. "What advantage does the salt inside the database give?" --- the biggest and the only salt advantage - to be random and different for each entry. It isn't intended to be secret. PS: CS is a science around *knowledge*, not *feelings*

Comment: But we are not talking about algorithms, we are talking about which is more secure, salt inside DB or salt inside of a file. With salt inside the PHP file, it adds another LAYER of security.

Comment: @AustinAllover: I can repeat it once again: until you know the algorithm - you cannot start bruteforce passwords, just because you don't know the algorithm. You see - the known salt isn't less secured. So even if you know the hash and the salt - it doesn't allow you to do anything until you know the algorithm for sure.

Comment: If the attacker can register on your site, they can match the hash from the database with their password by hashing using many different algorithms. This technique is not possible without a valid salt. I see no advantage to storing the salt inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

A different salt for each hash; otherwise the hashed object becomes vulnerable to a brute force attack.

Comment: Anything is vulnerable to brute force

Comment: @zerkms: I disagree.  Brute force attacks will always work (eventually) but a well salted password is not "vulnerable"... to be vulnerable there needs to be an exploitable weakness.  Like using the same salt.

Comment: bruteforce is called "**brute-**" because it is just a bruting items one by one. There is no protection from bruteforce. Every hash is vulnerable to bruteforce by definition. If we know salt (and obviously we do) - we can apply bruteforce.

Comment: @zerkms: I think we have different contexts of "vulnerable".  I am speaking in comparative terms; you are speaking in absolutes.  As I said, brute force attacks will always work, but a well-salted password hash makes it much harder to do.  It is more resistant.  If every hashing technique is "vulnerable" to an attack, doesn't it make sense to couch your frame of reference in terms of comparison?

Comment: I don't know what is "well-salted". For me the secret string (password) is either salted, or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re storing passwords in a database, you need to mix in something that varies per entry so that you cannot easily find matching passwords within the database. You can use a random salt, or you can just include the username (if it's immutable) or some other immutable unique field.

If you use something like a username then you should also do something that’s unique to your implementation since there are probably other sites using the same algorithm and therefore there’s a chance of spotting matches. Strictly speaking, it doesn’t have to be a salt that you include in the hash, it could just be a difference in the way that your algorithm works, but it’s usually simplest to just add a global salt. If you’re using a per entry salt, then there’s no need to add another global salt.

With these kinds of issues, it's usually simplest to think of the kinds of attacks that hackers might use. Remember, you’re not actually trying to safeguard your data (since your database has been compromised), you’re actually trying to stop hackers from taking the credentials used on your site and using them on other sites.